# Error: "no such directory" when running click package on phone.

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4, click-packages

Error: "no such directory" when running click package on phone.

On my desktop it works. Testing it out on the phone though, it does not work. The error stems from the import of that folder called "Components".

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I went to my .pro file and found this:

```
#specify where the qml/js files are installed to
qml_files.path = /Poker-Puzzle
qml_files.files += $${QML_FILES}
```

changed it to this:

```
#specify where the qml/js files are installed to
qml_files.path = /Poker-Puzzle/QML/components
qml_files.files += $${QML_FILES}
```